# What is the official Gentoo AMI?

Tags: gentoo, amazon-ec2

I would like to use Gentoo on Amazon EC2.

What are the right AMI for me to use?

I won't be running X unless necessary. I guess I need a *server* variant, if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could not find an official build for EC2. The closes thing is likely going to be the [Pygoscelis Papua Linux distro](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/products/pygoscelis-papua/).

> Dowd and Associates is offering Pygoscelis Papua Linux. Pygoscelis Papua Linux is an unofficial build of Gentoo Linux for Amazon EC2.

You can also peruse the Cloud Market list of images available.

- [The Cloud Market Gentoo Images](http://thecloudmarket.com/platform/gentoo)

If you'd rather there are other methods discussed within these resources which cover rolling your own Gentoo image from scratch.

- [Gentoo in Cloud](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/products/gentoo-in-the-cloud/)
- [Gentoo EC2 Tutorial / Bootstrapping](http://rich0gentoo.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/gentoo-ec2-tutorial-bootstrapping/)
- [Multiple WordPress Blogs, Gentoo Linux, and Amazon EC2](https://www.softwareab.net/wordpress/wordpress-gentoo-linux-amazon-ec2/)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Pygoscelis Papua. Should Cloud Market images always be more expensive than the regular AMIs? Can I use them with Spot instances?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov - I cannot say. I'm not familiar with any of this really, I was merely trying to provide you leads/resources to pursue your Q. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the links to creating your own Gentoo AMI.  *THAT* was what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

There's now Funtoo which is a variant from one of the Gentoo developers, pretty similar except a few minor differences such as ego sync instead of emerge --sync, but everything else with emerge, configurations, paths, etc. seems okay.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=4397dfe5-25e8-4f7c-8666-b03c6daccf0a